# How to load big csv file with mixed-type columns using the bigmemory package

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, large-files, import-from-csv

Is there a way to combine the use of scan() and read.big.matrix() from the bigmemory package to read in a 200 MB .csv file with mixed-type columns so that the result is a dataframe with integer, character, and numeric columns?

Comment: does it have to be the bigmemory package? I find ff much more useful for this sort of stuff

Comment: @mdsumner is on the right track.  Does it even need to be file-backed?  For 200MB, I'd just read it in, work with it, then save it as 1 or more BM files (or in `ff`, if you wish).

Answer (score 9):

Try the ff package for this.

```
library(ff)
help(read.table.ffdf)
```

> Function ‘read.table.ffdf’ reads separated flat files into ‘ffdf’
>      objects, very much like (and using) ‘read.table’.  It can also
>       work with any convenience wrappers like ‘read.csv’ and provides
>       its own convenience wrapper (e.g. ‘read.csv.ffdf’) for R's usual
>       wrappers.

For 200Mb it should be as simple a task as this.

```
 x <- read.csv.ffdf(file=csvfile)
```

(For much bigger files it will likely require that you investigate some of the configuration options, depending on your machine and OS).

Comment: Thank you mdsummer. I tried the ff package, was able to read in the almost 300 MB dataset which I stored into an object which I later coerced into a dataframe with as.data.frame. However, this ate up so much memory that there was little left for analysis. It was a good start though and a helpful suggestion.

Comment: The entire point is not to load it all in but use the memory-mapped features of the ff package. There are tools to extract portions from the ff data structures

Answer (score 7):

Ah, there are some things that are impossible in this life, and there are some that are misunderstood and lead to unpleasant situations.  @Roman is right: a matrix must be of one atomic type.  It's not a dataframe.

Since a matrix must be of one type, attempting to snooker `bigmemory` to handle multiple types is, in itself, a bad thing.  Could it be done? I'm not going there.  Why? Because everything else will assume that it's getting a matrix, not a dataframe. That will lead to more questions and more sorrow.

Now, what you can do is to identify the types of each of the columns, and generate a set of distinct bigmemory files, each containing the items that are of a particular type.  E.g. charBM = character big matrix, intBM = integer big matrix, and so on.  Then, you may be able to develop have a wrapper that produces a data frame out of all of this.  Still I don't recommend that: treat the different items as what they are, or coerce homogeneity if you can, rather than try to produce a big dataframe griffin.

@mdsumner is correct in suggesting `ff`.  Another storage option is HDF5, which you can access through `ncdf4` in R.  Unfortunately, these other packages are not as pleasant as `bigmemory`.

Comment: Thanks Iterator. You are right, the other packages are not as pleasant as bigmemory.

Answer (score 4):

According to the help file, no.

> Files must contain only one atomic type (all integer, for example).
>   You, the user, should know whether your file has row and/or column
>   names, and various combinations of options should be helpful in
>   obtaining the desired behavior.

I'm not familiar with this package/function, but in R, matrices can have only one atomic type (unlike e.g. data.frames).

Comment: Thanks for your two cents. On this blog, http://joshpaulson.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/michael-kane-on-bigmemory/ someone suggested that a workaround to the limitation of matrices having only one atomic type (a characteristic inherited by big.matrix) is to use scan(). I was hoping someone could share their experiences with read.big.matrix from the bigmemory package, especially with regards to reading in mixed-type columns and whether they have used scan().

Comment: Maybe you can do that in the processing stage, but I would like to be proven wrong (sensu @Iterator).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to read the file line by line and parse it, in this way the reading process will occupy an amount of memory almost linear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! However, this does not answer the question, which was specifically aimed at the bigmemory package