# How to load a big csv using ff package?

Tags: linux, r, bigdata, ff

I'm new at R.
I have a big csv around 2.5 gb with 3 columns and 40 million rows. The datatypes of the column are interger, datetime and char. How to load this csv using ff package?

Comment: Also there are some null values in each of the columns

Comment: Doese Aashu's answer solve your problem? You should verify this answer if it help you

Answer (score 0):

Well it will give you some idea and use existing links [Save and load your bigData](http://rforwork.info/tag/ff/) ,[load big csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970742/how-to-load-big-csv-file-with-mixed-type-columns-using-the-bigmemory-package)

```
all <- read.csv("file.csv")
    library("ff")
    help(read.table.ffdf)
    x<- read.csv.ffdf(file="file.csv", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=10000, next.rows=50000, colClasses=NA)
    save.ffdf(ffdfname, dir=”/PATH/TO/STORE/FF/FILES”)
    load.ffdf(dir=”/PATH/TO/STORE/FF/FILES”)
```

hope it will help you.